# “ctrl”+“F”—keyboard shortcut of “Find” option—is not working in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

In one of my PC if press <kbd>crtl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (find) in Internet Explorer then it’s not working (Find option does not come). But in chrome this option works. Actually IE also has option of <kbd>crtl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for search option.

I tried removing all addins from Internet Explorer and also used safe mode in Internet Explorer but it didn’t help. So please, can anyone tell me what may be the reason behind it?

Comment: Did it ever work? What AV do you have? Are you using a program like Comodo or any key mapping?

Comment: since you are facing issue in I.E 8 alone,Can you please try to reset the settings by going to tools -> Internet options ->Advanced -> Reset Internet Explorer settings and check whether still you are facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Start Internet Explorer.   On the Tools menu, click Internet Options. 
>   Under the Advanced tab, click Reset.   In the dialog box Reset
>   Internet Explorer Settings, click Reset to confirm your choice.
>
> If this doesn't work try the following:
>
> Exit out of Internet Explorer. type Ctrl-Esc to bring up search bar,
>   and type "cmd". Right click and choose "run as administrator". When
>   the command window opens type "regsvr32 oleacc.dll". Open Internet
>   Explorer back up and Ctrl-F should work fine.

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/ctrlf-search-function-in-ie8/d448514b-267b-4d7c-839a-173540d747fa)

---

Most of this is for IE9 but it should apply to IE 8... You could just update to IE 10 and not be 2 versions behind? :)

> Have you implemented the menu bar?  If not, that may resolve the problem (or at least give you a way using Edit / Find to bring up the appropriate toolbar that for me appears under the favorites bar when activated).   Here's how to add the Menu Bar: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/29533/always-show-the-menu-other-toolbars-bar-in-internet-explorer-9-beta/.
>
> Troubleshooting and Internet Explorer’s (No Add-ons) Mode
>   http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2006/07/25/678113.aspx
>
> Does the behavior persist if you Reset IE Advanced settings (RIES)?
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923737
>
> If they don't work, uninstall IE9 and then re-install it again. But
>   let's be sure we install it the right way.
>
> First, lets make sure we've covered any problems such as missing
>   prerequisites and such. Follow the instructions in this
>   article:http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2409098. Ignore the
>   recommended download locations in the article and use the one that
>   follows:
>
> Go
>   to:http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/downloads/ie-9/worldwide-languages
>   and select languages and locales under the download now button and
>   then choose your language and then your version of Vista (possibly you
>   were getting the wrong version in WU or from another site if that's
>   how you upgraded). When it prompts to download, select "Save As" and
>   browse to your Desktop and save it there.
>
> Once the download is complete, go to your desktop and the installation
>   program icon should be there. Right click on it and click on Run as
>   Administrator (even if you are already logged in as an administrator)
>   and it should proceed with the installation (this process sometimes
>   helps with installations). Reboot when done and when you return,
>   hopefully IE9 will be installed and working.
>
> If that doesn't work, check out the following article on
>   troubleshooting IE9 installation problems:
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2409098.

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_vista/the-ctrl-f-doesnt-work-ctrl-f-doesnt-bring-up-the/53c332ed-b16a-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5?msgId=f5f9c760-b86a-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5)

---

This is not tested, do so at your own risk and research the oleacc.dll first!

> Resolution – To resolve the issue, you should re-register oleacc.dll
>   file. Follow the steps mentioned below:
>
> Click Start
>
> Click All Programs, Accessories
>
> Right-click Command Prompt and select “Run as Administrator” as shown
>   below:
>
> At the command prompt, type the following:
>
> ```
> regsvr32 oleacc.dll
> ```
>
> This will resolve the issue.
>
> NOTE: Ensure that you have closed all the Internet Explorer windows,
>   while performing this task.
>
> Open IE now and select Find. You will be able to see the Find bar

[Source](http://hostedbywho.co.uk/articles/find-ctrl-f-option-not-working-in-ie/)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this worked, but I right clicked the tool bar, selected "Show Tabs on a Separate Row", and then my ctrl-f started working again.  I turned the "Show Tabs on a Separate Row" and my ctrl-f continued to work.  Again, no idea why it worked, but it did.

Answer (score 0):

On my Windows 11 Ctrl and F was not working.  However I found that SHIFT and F brings up a search box on the bottom tool bar. This Works for searches in the document open.